# Getting output of MS stored procedure on php call

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am using the sqlsrv ms drivers for php, which work fine (tested with normal queries). I have also tested it with running a stored procedure to update a table data, which also works.

Now I want to use it to run a stored procedure, and I want to retrieve the response. How can this be done?

```
$server = "...the server address...";
$options = array("UID"=>"...the username...","PWD"=>"...the password...",
  "Database" => "...the database..."
  );

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $options);

if ($conn === false) {die("<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));}

$tsql_callSP = "{call ...the stored proc...( ?, ?)}";

$params = array( 
                 array("...first value in...", SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                 array("...second value in...", SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
               );

$stmt3 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql_callSP, $params);
if( $stmt3 === false )
{
     echo "Error in executing statement 3.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

print_r( $stmt3); //attempting to print the return but all i get is Resource id #3
echo "test echo";

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt3);
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
```

I know that I can use an output parameter, but I will always receive multiple values from the stored proc.

Comment: The answer is simple sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt3), the reason I have not removed the question is I didn't see any similar posts with this code. So im leaving it up for anyone else looking to use SP's and PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing that the stored procedure is returning the contents of one table with a single SELECT statement, using its output should be as simple as using the result of sqlsrv_query as you would any other selection query result (i.e. using sqlsrv_fetch_object/array on the result)!
So the stored proc could look something like this:

```
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE test
AS
    -- do some other stuff here
    -- ...
    SELECT * FROM test
GO
```

And in your php:

```
// establish db connection, initialize
// ...

$sql = "{call test}"
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
while (sqlsrv_fetch_object($result))
{
     // do something with the data
     // ...
}
```

Comment: This still returns the resounce id. Except I am using this "Insert Into Table (ColumnName) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID Values ('SomeColumnValue')" instead of stored proc. Will the OUTPUT in sql return like a stored procedure?

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `sqlsrv_fetch()` and `sqlsrv_get_field()` to get data from the returned statement.

[From the example code in the manual for sqlsrv_get_field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296207.aspx):

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
if( $stmt === false )
{
     echo "Error in statement preparation/execution.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

/* Make the first row of the result set available for reading. */
if( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ) === false )
{
     echo "Error in retrieving row.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

/* Note: Fields must be accessed in order.
Get the first field of the row. Note that no return type is
specified. Data will be returned as a string, the default for
a field of type nvarchar.*/
$name = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 0);
echo "$name: ";
```

Beyond that, I am not sure when you say you will receive multiple values whether you mean there will be multiple fields in one row (in which case you will want to make more calls to `sqlsrv_get_field()`), more than one row (in which case you will have to use a while loop with the call to [sqlsrv_fetch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296187.aspx) in the loop), or more than one result set (in which case you'll want a while loop using [sqlsrv_next_result()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296167.aspx)).