# Call SQL Server stored procedure with output parameter from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to execute a sql server stored procedure from php. Stored procedure returns a output value. I want that value in php to display in webpage.

Everything works fine except the output value returns 0 in php.. but the row is getting inserted perfectly. the output value shows as 0. annoyed where I have made the mistake. Below is my php code

```
require('db.php');   

    $billno = "REF0001";  
    $retsno = 0.0;  

    $sp_name = "{call testinsert( ?, ? )}";

    $params = array(   
                     array($billno, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),  
                     array($retsno, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT)  
                   );  

    /* Execute the query. */  
    $stmt3 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sp_name, $params);  
    if( $stmt3 === false )  
    {  
         echo "Error in executing statement 3.\n";  
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
    }  


    echo "Inserted Retuern Sno for ".$billno." is ". $retsno. ".";
```

and my stored procedure is

```
create procedure testinsert(@bill_no VARCHAR(20),@RetSno INT OUTPUT)
as
begin
    insert into testable values(@bill_no,GETDATE())
    set @RetSno = @@IDENTITY
    return
end
```

Comment: Those variables aren't being modified so when you echo them you get their initial values (REF0001, 0,0). you need to assign the updated values to those variables. Or am I missing something?

Comment: PLease try if you get the correct response when you replace the `@@IDENTITY` with a normal number.

Comment: Andy I tried that too. i simply returned a vague value from stored procedure. still it returns 0.

Comment: @OfirBaruch is right, `sqlsrv_query` just uses your `$params`-Array but doesn't overwrite anything in it

Comment: what cud be the solution?

Comment: May you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8355639/4190467 with the MS PHP-Driver

Comment: I might be stupid to suggest this, but would `$params = [ [ $billno, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN] , [ &$retsno, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT ] ];` work?

Comment: Try to modify your stored procedure and use "sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt3)"

Comment: The solution of @OfirBaruch should work. You can use after the fetch-Statement `var_dump($stmt3);` to see what you got as the response

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed scrollable. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh487160(v=sql.105).aspx

```
$stmt3 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sp_name, $params, array( "Scrollable" => 'static'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you use your `echo`, add the following line to read the next line:

```
sqlsrv_fetch($stmt3);
```

Then you can select the first field of the response, which should be your parameter, with [`sqlsrv_get_field()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.sqlsrv-get-field.php):

```
$id = sqlsrv_get_field(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same case, and solved it using:

```
sqlsrv_next_result($stmt);
```

at the end of the instruction. Here I put part of my code in case it helps you.

```
    $totalPaginas = 0;
    $result = array();
    $query = "EXEC DBO.SPS_EJECUTAR_CONSULTA @ReporteID = ?, @FilasPorPagina = ?, @NroPagina = ?, @TotalPaginas = ?";
    $params = array(
        array(&$reporteid, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
        array(&$filasPorPagina, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
        array(&$nroPagina, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
        array(&$totalPaginas, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT)
    );
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($this->db, $query, $params);
    if( !$stmt ) {
        // show errors
    }
    $result = sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
    if( !$result ) {
        // show errors
    }
    $data = array();
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    sqlsrv_next_result($stmt);
    var_dum($data);
    echo('Total Paginas: '.$totalPaginas);
```

Officially tells you how to do it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-retrieve-input-and-output-parameters-using-the-sqlsrv-driver